# Hiding an element in the layout on Activity Result

Tags: android, textview, visibility, unreachable-code

I'm trying to hide a textView in my layout after I receive a result from an activity. I have a variable declaration - View lblEmptyList, which I instantiate in the onCreate:

```
lblEmptyList = findViewById(R.id.emptyList);
```

I tried this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            switch (requestCode) {

            case 1:
...
lblEmptyList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But I'm getting an "Unreachable code" error.
I tried to access it directly like that:

```
findViewById(R.id.emptyList).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

I tried to use numeric values instead of View.GONE, but I keep getting this "Unreachable code" error. How do I fix it?

Comment: "Unreachable code" error means that your code will not be reached at runtime(it's a condition that is never true or something like that). it's nothing wrong with lblEmptyList.setVisibility(View.GONE) syntax.

Comment: Look into your code. Do you have before setVisibility line something like throw Exception or return statement.

Comment: Got it! I moved this line before the rest of the code and then it worked just fine. Thank you both very much!

Answer (score 0):

The `lblEmptyList.setVisibility(View.GONE);` line had to be executed before the rest of the code.